# Mysql (MariaDB 10.0.29): Set root password, but still can login without asking password?

Tags: mysql, authentication, passwords, mariadb

I want to secure mysql by setting root password.
I reset root password successfully:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select Host, User, Password from mysql.user;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| Host      | User | Password                                  |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
| localhost | root | *58319282EAB9E38D49CA25844B73DA62C80C2ABC |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But, after flush privileges, restart Mysql, I can still login mysql (on local host) without typing password.

```
root@myhost:/# mysql
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 10
Server version: 10.0.29-MariaDB SLE 12 SP1 package

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

How can I force mysql asking password when connect ? Thanks !

Answer (score 76):

On MySQL table you have a column called plugin:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT host, user, password, plugin FROM mysql.user LIMIT 0,1;
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
| host      | user | password                                  | plugin |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
| localhost | root | *                                         |        |
+-----------+------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If I remember correctly the default plugin for mariaDB installations are 'console' or 'unix_socket', and this plugin allows you to enter without password, from console. But also disable authentication with password, and you cannot connect from another clients.

Simply update the plugin field with empty ('') value, and then, use FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = '' WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

With this, you have the problem solved.

Comment: Thankyou @Sakura Kinomoto. I did that but still no luck!

Comment: No luck... check your mysql.user table for if there's another user with the plugin enabled. Maybe you're login with another line, for example root@%

Comment: `code`MariaDB [(none)]> select Host,User, Password,plugin from mysql.user;
+-----------+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
| Host      | User   | Password                                  | plugin |
+-----------+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
| localhost | root   | *58319282EAB9E38D49CA25844B73DA62C80C2ABC |        |
+-----------+--------+-------------------------------------------+--------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)`code`
I am sure table user has just one record (root@localhost) with empty plugin value.

Comment: Thank you @SakuraKinomoto. Your guidance and a restart (Debian Stretch) worked a treat for me! :)

Comment: Perfect this solution works Great on Mariadb 10.1.26

Comment: Awesome man . You are a life saver. :D  # worked on 10.0.36-MariaDB

Answer (score 8):

I found I needed to change this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'auth_socket' WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost';
```

To

```
 UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE user = 'root' AND host = 'localhost';
```

That is the plugin for a password AFAICT.

Answer (score 6):

For Server version: 10.7.5-MariaDB

I solved this problem by following steps:

Using command `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';`

If you see a line similar to this one

> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED VIA
> mysql_native_password USING
> 'A_HASH_PASSWORD' OR unix_socket WITH GRANT
> OPTION

That means your root user can be authenticated by 2 methods password or unix_socket.

Now you can use command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `root`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'YOUR_RAW_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Alternatively, I used: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO \`root\`@\`localhost\` IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING 'YOUR_RAW_PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I had the same issue and the steps below solved my problem:

on the Linux terminal, run the command below to set a new password for root user, skip this step, if root password is already set.

```
mysqladmin --user=root password "newpassword"
```

Login to mysql

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

Enter 'root' user password

Run following query on MariaDB console

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select host,user,password from mysql.user;
```

You may notice some records with 'user' column values are ''(empty), delete those records using following query

```
MariaDB [(none)]> delete from mysql.user where user='';
MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges;
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye
#$ mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

You wont be able to login to mysql without password after following above steps.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me.

After installation

```
sudo mysql
```

to login.

Then

```
alter user root@localhost identified via '';
flush privileges;
\q
```

Now you can login as root without password from localhost as had been the default behavior before.

```
mysql -uroot
```

Comment: this returns 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY 'PAs7@O'' at line 1`

Comment: version mariadb 8