# mysql secure installation seems to be not secure

Tags: mysql, database-connection, database-security, mariadb-10.5

After successful `mysql_secure_installation`

Output:

```
mysql_secure_installation
Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
Switch to unix_socket authentication [Y/n] n
Change the root password? [Y/n] y
New password:
MyBullPassword
Re-enter new password: 
MyBullPassword
Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] n
Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
```

When I run:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

I AM able to connect to mysql without password or even with wrong password and instead of "access denied" message I'm connected to the MySQL server.

So I guess MySQL is not secured

Why?
What am I doing wrong?
Is is possible because I'm connected to the server as root?
mysql gives me acssess even with wrong password?

OS: Centos 8
MySQL: MariaDB 10.5.8

Comment: Please decrease amount of capital letters in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for few things in your installation:

- Socket connections - are they enabled or disabled
- User specific configuration in `my.cnf`

There is a lot of information how to perform these checks and how to fix your issue here - [How to disable MySQL root logins when no password is supplied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179894/how-to-disable-mysql-root-logins-when-no-password-is-supplied)

Comment: When I run this

SELECT host, user, password, plugin FROM mysql.user;

Comment: | Host      | User        | Password                                  | plugin                |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| localhost | mariadb.sys |                                           | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | root        | *CB48266FCF86AC2CA4EDA9DAC8D9F41D946F9A0E | mysql_native_password |
| localhost | mysql       | invalid                                   | mysql_native_password |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+

Comment: plugin  :mysql_native_password

Comment: Socket connections - how can I  find if  they are enabled or disabled?

Comment: /etc/my.cnf
#
# This group is read both by the client and the server
# use it for options that affect everything
#
[client-server]

#
# include *.cnf from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d

Comment: with wrong password i get: SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
root@localhost root@localhost

Comment: Do you even read what I share? Please take a look at it again.